# Pandas- Groupby Plot is not working for object

Tags: pandas, plot

I am new to Pandas and doing some analysis csv file. I have successfully read csv and shown all details. I have got two column as an object type which I need to plot. I have done groupy for those two columns and getting first and all data, However I am not sure, how to do plotting for these object types in Pandas. Below is my sample of Groupby and smaple for event_type and event_description for which I need to do plotting. If I can plot for Application and Network for event_type that will be great help

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('/Users/temp/Downloads/sample.csv’)
data.head()
grouped_df = data.groupby([ "event_type", "event_description"])
grouped_df.first()
```

[image]

Comment: Need some more information here - what are you trying to plot? Can't read the output either - try generating a fake dataset/model to work with (and share that), and mock up how the plot may look based on this.

Comment: If I can plot bar that will be great help, like number of event_type for Application, Network, Page Name should be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented - need more info, but IIUC, try:

`df['event_type'].value_counts(sort=True).plot(kind='barh')`

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I was looking for this and got exactly right things. Once again thanks. Also if we want both event_type and event_description in on plot, can it be done.